# Illustrator scripting document.close() method crash

Tags: scripting, adobe-illustrator

In Illustrator CS6, I want to export all selections to each SVG files.
My sequence is this.

1. Make temporary document, using `documents.addDocument()` method
2. Copy `i`th selections to temporary document.
3. Export using `document.exportFile()` method as SVG file.
4. Use `document.close()` method to close temporary document.

But Illustrator crashes when reached sequence 4.
What is the problem?

```
var sel = activeDocument.selection;

var arr = new Array;
for(var i=0;i<sel.length;i++)
{   
    arr.push(sel[i]);
}

var preset = new DocumentPreset;
var option = new ExportOptionsSVG;
option.compressed = false;
option.fontType = SVGFontType.OUTLINEFONT;

for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
{
    doc = app.documents.addDocument(i,preset);  //sequence 1
    var item = arr[i].duplicate();          //sequence 2
    item.move(doc,ElementPlacement.PLACEATEND);

    expFile = new File("C:\\Users\\user\\Documents\\font project\\svg\\" + i);

    doc.exportFile(expFile,ExportType.SVG,option);  //sequence 3

    doc.close();    //sequence 4 and it occurs crashes
}
```

*export directory exists and it is empty.

Answer (score 0):

I have just run your code in Illustrator CC 2017, it is working fine. May be in the older version Illustrator have some issues. Why don't you switch to the latest version of Illustrator? Right now I am not having CS6, but I will try on CS6 as well and let you know.